# Index creation and memory issue on Couchbase version 6.6

Tags: couchbase

Running a single node server and the index creation sometimes fails with the following message:

```
GSI CreateIndex() - cause: Create index or Alter replica cannot proceed due to rebalance in progress, another concurrent create index request, network partition, node failover, indexer failure, or presence of duplicate index name.
```

It takes a very long time to recover from this and invariably restarting the server would fix the issue. I’ve checked the query.log and indexer.log files and nothing there suggests that any of the above mentioned scenarios might be happening.

Also, the server is running on a 16GB machine and the total allocated memory for the CB services is 12GB. But the memory used sometimes shoots upto ~15GB.

Is there something that I’m missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Community or Enterprise?

Comment: @MatthewGroves Community one.

Answer (score 1):

Memory leak is usually caused because of OS settings not being set up correct, especially the THP.
Please ensure you have done the following.

1. Snappiness -- https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-swap-space.html
2. Transparent Huge Pages -- https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/thp-disable.html